# Cannot deploy ADF application onto Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have jDeveloper 12c on Windows and WebLogic Server 12c on a Linux (as a remote server).
Im trying to deploy my application onto the weblogic on linux, but to no avail.

This is the error msg i've encounter.

```
[01:30:05 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[01:30:05 PM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 10.3).
[01:30:05 PM] Retrieving existing application information
[01:30:05 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[01:30:05 PM] Building...
[01:30:06 PM] Deploying profile...
[01:30:08 PM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestApp\ViewController\deploy\TestApp_ViewController_webapp.war
[01:30:08 PM] Deploying Application...
[01:40:09 PM] weblogic.deploy.api.spi.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: [J2EE Deployment SPI:260041]Unable to upload "C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestApp\ViewController\deploy\TestApp_ViewController_webapp.war" to "t3://10.186.116.221:7001"
[01:40:09 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[01:40:09 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[01:40:09 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
```

Tested connection and all, it works out fine.

Comment: Could be an network issue. Did your configure JDeveloper to use the correct network settings (like proxy etc.)? Can you deploy your application trough the admin console?

Comment: @User404 yes thanks a bunch! it was the proxy and some other libraries issues